# filling a matrix using recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, matrix

As a practice for recursion i was trying to fill a 2-D array using recursion
For simplicity i took the value to be inserted to be the addition of `row index(rowV)` and `column index(colV)`.
`eg. a[3][3] would be equal to 6`
where `int a[][]=new int[3][3]`
the code below iterates from `index #22 to index #20` and then gives the infamous `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` error.

```
 void fill(int rowV, int colV){

    if(rowV==-1 && colV==-1){
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
    else{
        a[rowV][colV]=(rowV+colV);
        if(rowV%2==0){ fill(rowV, colV-1);rowV--;}
        else if(colV%2==0){fill(colV,rowV-1);}
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the definition of the variable `a`

Comment: @ByteHamster sorry my bad, `a` is a square matrix of dimension [3] [3]

Comment: How do you call the function `fill` in the first place? Which parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running through it on paper from the first call,

```
fill(2,2)
```

This will fill the 22 element, and trigger the

```
if(rowV%2==0){ fill(rowV, colV-1);rowV--;}
```

line, which will call

```
fill(2,1)
```

This will fill the 21 element, and trigger the

```
if(rowV%2==0){ fill(rowV, colV-1);rowV--;}
```

line, and so on (my answer is recursive too)...

Essentially, you will never reach a line where the `rowV` variable is decremented, until all of the recursive function calls (which fill the matrix) have been evaluated, by which time it is too late for them to have any effect.

Be careful with recursion!

Answer (score 0):

Your stopping condition only stops when both `rowV` and `colV` are -1. If only one of them is -1, you'll try to assign a value to an invalid index of the array.

Comment: oh okay, but even when i changed my condition to `if(rowV==-1 || colV==-1)` the array index of `00, 01, 02, 10, 11, 12` are untouched by the recursive calls. Only `20, 21, 22` are affected